# How to make web essentials compile my less into min.css on build ?

Tags: less, web-essentials

So web essentials is no longer building my main .less file into a min.css file.

I haven't changed any settings, and web essentials is up to date.

Here are my web essentials LESS settings:

[image: Web Essentials Less Settings]

Please Help !

Answer (score 6):

Did you try checking the CSS setting mentioned in this blog post:

[Visual Studio Web Essentials: keep your settings in sync](http://blog.falafel.com/visual-studio-web-essentials-keep-your-settings-in-sync/)

In the blog article linked to, it talks about a similar scenario and suggests also taking a look in Visual Studio at Tools > Options > Web Essentials > CSS. From here you want to check and see that in the Minification section that Minify files on save is set to **True**.

Comment: Thanks @Khilley! I had to restart Visual Studio after changing this setting, for the compile to work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this problem I had the same thing where it doesn't compile on save. 
I fixed it by downloading the Web Compiler part of the Web Essentials pack. The link for the compiler is here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler

Now when I save my .less file it will update the less.min file :) Hope that saves anyone time and trouble!!